# CSRF simulation test for django app

Tags: django, django-testing

I would like simulate **Cross Site Request Forgery** query.

My query has to try change number of votes for choice. Add +1 to "choice.votes" pole in database. There is a **form** to vote with radiobutons for choices and <kbd>submit</kbd> button to call function "vote".

```
# I've followed django tutorial 
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial05/
# Some details about my model:

>>> q = Question.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> q
<Question: spam or egg?>
>>> my_choice = q.choice_set.get(pk=1)
>>> my_choice
<Choice: spam>
>>> my_choice.votes
0
```

I can simulate 'attack' by hand sending post with keyword `{'choice': my_choice.id}` using postman application but **I need write a django application test**.

So far in my test I used `django.test.Client` like this:

```
class ChoiceVoteTests(TestCase):
    def test_vote_on_non_existing_question(self):
        non_existing_pk = 2
        q = create_question("q_text", days=-10)
        c = create_choice(q, "c_text", votes=0)
        url = reverse('polls:vote', args=(non_existing_pk,))
        response = self.client.get(url)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 404)
```

but using `self.client.post(url, data={'choice': my_choice.id})` **make simulation of a real user that clicks on my submit button** that I don't want to test.

---

EDIT:

```
url = reverse('polls:vote', args=(past_q.pk,)) + '?choice=' + str(past_c.id)
response = self.client.post(url)
```

also doesn't work.
How to just send raw post `polls/1/vote?choice=1` **without using client**?

Comment: I'm confused about what is wrong with using the test client and how it is different from what you do want.

Comment: Client instance simulate an real person that politely clicks the "submit" button using the form. This should increase votes number - and it does. But if you tried send post to vote on question outside of the form (for example to vote on a choice of hidden question, not publicated yet) using like URL like this: 'polls/5/vote?choice=2', it should give 403 Forbidden status code. That is why we used to use crsf_token in django (see more: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/csrf/). I would like to simulate this type of action. I can do that using postman (403 is result) but not using Client.

Comment: That's not a _cross-site_ request forgery attack, that's just an invalid request. And why wouldn't you be able to pass in invalid input through the Client and test for a 403 response?